# How would you display hundreds of sports teams for a user to choose from?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application

I have been wrestling with this problem for a couple of days. I have hundreds of sports teams broken down by leagues and geographic locations.

For example:

```
    English Premier League: Manchester United, Liverpool, Arsenal .....(total 20)
    Italian Serie A: Juventus, AC Milan, Roma... (total 20)
    .
    .
    .
    Around 20 other leagues
    In addition to national teams broken down by continent.
```

Users are supposed to choose their favorite team on a mobile app.

How would you go about this?

Here are some options I thought about:

1. Search + Autocomplete

   - Pros: Straightforward, users understand this approach
   - Cons: Requires typing, visually boring
2. An upper pane, once a league/continent is chosen, a bottom pane appears with corresponding teams in the main category

   - Pros: 2 taps only
   - Cons: Small icons on a small screen can be confusing
3. Expandable menus of the leagues. Tapping expands more teams

   - Pros: 2 Taps
   - Cons: Could require a lot of scrolling

Ideally I would like an option that is both visually appealing and innovative + requires two taps only. Any takers?

Comment: I think setting favorite isn't primary activity, it's rather integrated into browsing and viewing activities. However, both search+autocomplete and browsing across leagues/countries are required functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are blessed with a knowledgeable user who knows the information they are trying to find. Seriously consider the Auto-complete / auto suggestion option as it's likely to offer the right team in a short list after 3 - 4 letters have been typed.

Consider finding my home town in Google maps. Should I find "UK" from a list of countries, then find "Hampshire" in a list of counties, then scan down for "Southampton" from a list of towns? That's how a lot of old sat-navs used to work and, from personal experience, it's cumbersome. Google provides me with the ability to type "southa" into a box and find "Southampton" immediately.

Essentially, I don't agree that typing is inherently a 'con', or that visually boring is a consideration that comes above ease of use and immediacy for a user.

Is Google's home page search box visually boring? Maybe. Is it useful? yes :o)

Saying that, if you really want to know which is best, build an HTML prototype of each and ask people to try them out - see which is easiest. Then you'll know for sure and can stop stressing :o)

You could use twitter typeahead for your first suggestion: https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me

And a few link-filled HTML pages would do for each of 2 and 3, or knock some up using twitter Boostrap's "Collapse" feature http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

I'd suggest using Bootstrap as you can quickly mock something up that can be viewed on a phone viewport.

Answer (score 4):

Type and find is the best way. If you want to make it visually appealing, displaying the team logos as you type might help. I think if I have a fav team, I would identify it by the logo asap.

So if I type 'Man', I would see the logos of Manchester city and Manchester United making it easy to select.

Answer (score 2):

Tap count is not really a determining factor in UI efficiency, but the UI described below is efficient in the (likely?) case that multiple teams of interest are from same the country and same league.  If a UI is fun, efficient enough, and not used very often then tap count is somewhat irrelevant [See full argument here](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/stop-counting-clicks/)

The continent / country filter can be done via image of a map (i.e. an outline of world map with clear hotspots). One click to zoom a continent (or FIFA region) and another to select the the country.

- When in a Continent / FIFA Region is selected can list the National Teams.
- When a country is selected can list it's leagues + teams in that country in a sectioned scrolling list (also it's national team)

This should give nice balance of visual attractiveness and efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

The best and most efficient way of displaying this information would be displaying a list of leagues that include there logos then from there on they can choose their team. Also a search bar with auto complete to accompany that.

An example > (Very rough drawing)

[image: Rough Drawing]

The user can either search for leagues or teams and the box/table automatically changes with the auto-complete function, they can then choose a league or choose a team to add.